# Test command: duplicate header row in log

Tags: shell, unix, testing, ksh

I have a script that is inventorying (not sure if thats a word) my environment.

It goes out and pulls Hostname OS, IP, and ENV (dev, prod, etc)..then spits all that to a logfile

At the top of my script i have a check to see if the logfile exist.

```
[[ -f $LOGFILE ]] || touch $LOGFILE && echo "ENV" "\t" "HOSTNAME" "\t" "OS" "\t" "IPADDRESS"
```

What i want it to do is IF exist, do nothing...otherwise touch and echo header to file.

Currently every run it echos the header row.

Comment: yes use them: [[ -f aaa ]] || (touch $LOGFILE && echo "ENV" "\t" "HOSTNAME" "\t" "OS" "\t" "IPADDRESS" > $LOGFILE)

Answer (score 0):

Mixing `||` and `&&` on the same line like this causes issues if the command after `||` succeeds. Expanding it to a full `if` statement is recommended.

```
if [[ ... ]]
then
   ...
else
   ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you give doesn't echo the line to your log file anyway.

```
[[ -f $LOGFILE ]] || printf "ENV\tHOSTNAME\tOS\tIPADDRESS" > $LOGFILE
```

`printf` interprets "\t" as a tab character. You don't need the touch command, since the file will be created and opened for writing by the output redirection.